# Show select file dialog in flash 15 error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, web

I'm using this library https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/ to provide uploading files functionality.
But it turned out it stopped working with the latest version of flash player (15).

For now I found out that code responsible for displaying select file dialog is not working,
it is just:

```
this.fileBrowser = new FileReference();
this.fileBrowser.browse();
```

and line `this.fileBrowser.browse();` doesn't work.
I'm not providing full code snippet.

Are there some more restricted ways of invoking such thing in new flash version?

---

Edit:

I'm providing more code maybe somebody know what is wrong here?

```
    try {
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "invoking browse()");
            this.fileBrowserOne.browse();

        } catch (ex:Error) {
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log", ex.toString());
            this.Debug("Exception: " + ex.toString());
        }
```

The function is invoked as a result of mouse click event, `this.fileBrowserOne.browse()` return `true` that should indicate that select file dialog opened correctly.
I can see all logs lines before and after method invocation. But the dialog is not showing up.

It happens only with Flash 15.0.0.152 and FF 32.0.2.
I haven't found any report on Internet about this issue but I cannot believe I'm the only one.

Comment: There should be no new restrictions in FP15. Do you get some kind of exception?

Comment: no, it is just not responding when I click a button that is invoking above code

Comment: Just tested `FileReference.browse()` in FP15 - no issues.   You're problem likely lies elsewhere - probably in the swfupload library (which looks old not not very good).  I'd recommend just using your own code instead of it.

Comment: Thanks for responses. I though about FP15 as a misbehaviour source because on e.g FP13 everything work perfect. But as you noticed library is old and maybe some code was FP version dependent.